# Dragonfly Imagemagick rotate, than crop than resize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dragonfly-gem

I am using a jQuery plugin that allows basic image manipulation: cropping, rotating, zooming, etc.

I am able to rotate the image:

```
image = photo.image.rotate(wrapper.rotate)
```

I am able to crop the image

```
image.thumb("#{wrapper.width}x#{wrapper.height}+#{wrapper.x}+#{wrapper.y}")
```

However, I can't figure out a way to resize the image after cropping it. Basically, I want to run:

```
 image.thumb("300x200!")
```

once more.

I understand that image.thumb() returns a Dragonfly job, is it possible to preform another process after cropping it?

Some context on why I want to do this: The user can pan over a specific area of the image which will than be visible in a 300x200px container. Most of the time, the image is way larger than 300x200px, so I want to re-size it after cropping it to reduce the filesize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of trying to do it with the given methods, just use .convert and pass the normal image magic arguments as one lone string e.g

```
image.convert("-gravity center -crop '#{wrapper.width}x#{wrapper.height}+#{wrapper.x}+#{wrapper.y}' -resize '300x200!'")
```

Comment: Perfect! One thing, I had to get rid of the -gravity argument for it to crop properly